# Why splice delete only last element?

Tags: reactjs

```
onRemoveVariant(groupKey, questionKey, variantKey) {
    const {questionGroups} = this.props;
    questionGroups[groupKey].questions[questionKey].variants.splice(variantKey, 1);
    this.props.updateQuestionnaire('questionGroups', questionGroups);
}
```

I have 5 variants and when i edit if i use delete variant first or any other variant, always only last variant get splice!
 Why? how to use splice if splice by key doesnt work?
[Img example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zqck3.png)

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the code for `render`, but you probably gave `index` as `key` when mapping the array

Comment: yes key it is index and when i test with number 0-3 ( it doesnt helped to me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the index of that particular element in an array and then use that index in place of splice(variantKey,1) as splice(index,1)

Comment: this doesnt work key it is index and when i test like splice(1, 1) this doesnt work and second element doesnt get remove (( only last element get removed(

Comment: `var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

function myFunction() {
  fruits.splice(2, 1);
}

fruits will be [ "Banana", "Orange", "Mango" ]`..

Similarly, when you use the index properly it has to work. Hope this helps